# Is there a way to make the displayed tab in Firefox "follow" the opened Inspector window(s)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When I am debugging frontend work, I frequently have multiple Inspector windows open at the same time, each inspecting a different page.  As I change Inspector windows, I would like the displayed tab or window to follow me.  In other words, I would like the browser to always automatically change to the page I am inspecting; I do not want to change Inspector windows, then go to the browser and find the corresponding tab or window myself.

Is this possible in Firefox?  Is it possible in *any* browser?

(I realize I could dock the Inspector to each tab or window.  I do not want to do that because I use the multiple Inspector windows side-by-side for comparison.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not aware of any way to switch to the target browser tab when selecting a given inspector window, you can certainly do it the other way around:

Say you have 3 tabs opened, and you have opened devtools for each them, in window-mode (undocked). Now, whenever you select any of these 3 tabs, if you just hit F12 (or ctrl+shift+I/cmd+alt+I), then the corresponding devtools window will be brought to the front.

That's an easy way to keep track of which devtools window is linked to which browser tab.

Now, doing this the other way around would require a new feature to be implemented. This can't really be automatic (or at least hidden behind a config of some sorts) because it could be considered frustrating to some users, having their current tab being switched away from each time they click in a devtools window.

I have filed this bug to get it done: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1163646

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and the reference to the bug/feature request, I'll subscribe to it.  Aside, I'd prefer a preference, not a keybinding and especially not a keybinding to a function key; I find function keys a nuisance to type on a laptop.